# How to Decode JSON with Dynamic key from FirebaseDatabase

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use JSONDecoder with FirebaseDatabase. There are some examples online, but I haven't been able to find one with dynamic object keys like the ones that are being returned in the response I am getting. Is there a better way to do this?

JSON Example:

```
{
"-LUOhAM5W42t9YxqFkUQ" =     {
    author =         {
        name = testName;
    };
    commentCount = 0;
    detail = "";
    id = "-LUOhAM5W42t9YxqFkUQ";
    likeCount = 0;
};
"-LUOhNU4wfwTlZQkrGFu" =     {
    author =         {
        name = otherName;
    };
    commentCount = 0;
    detail = "";
    id = "-LUOhNU4wfwTlZQkrGFu";
    likeCount = 0;
};
```

My Struct looks like this (I'm just trying to decode successfully first):

```
struct Post: Decodable {
    var id: String?
    var title: String?
}
```

And my code in my controller looks like this:

```
func getPosts() {
    Database.database().reference().child("posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let value = snapshot.value else { return }
        print("VALUE: \(value)")
        do {
            let person = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: value)
            print(person)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

I know I could loop through each object, decode and then add them to an array, but I'm looking for the most efficient approach and I really like the JSONDecoder. Again, the snag seems to be that Firebase puts the object key at the beginning of each object, which seems weird. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can decode a `[String: Post]` and just look at the `values` if you don't care about the keys

Comment: @dan I can get this to work, but it will cause a lot of additional setup. The posts are being returned in chronological order, so if I throw them into a dictionary, it will defeat the purpose and I will have to order them again on the front end. This will be especially inefficient in an activity feed with pagination when I start to add new posts to original response.

Comment: The snapshot being returned with your Firebase observe is ALL of the posts, not just one. You will need to iterate over the snapshot to get each individual post to work with. i.e. Post.self is one post, the snapshot contains a bunch.